# Shapes (triangles) being drawn incorrectly - HTML5 Canvas/JavaScript issue

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, geometry

[Here's](http://codepen.io/holmes/pen/xbOgRj) the pen for what I'm working on.

Experimenting with Canvas I've come across this issue and I can't work out why it's happening. The experiment is drawing triangles, and then detecting when the mouse goes over each one.

```
// loop to create triangles
for (var x=0;x<cols;x++) {
 for (var y=0;y<rows;y++){

  // random int for colour array
  var rand = getRandomInt(0, colours.length);

  // downward pointing triangles
  tri.push(new Triangle(x*tWidth,y*tWidth,(x*tWidth)+tWidth,y*tWidth,(x*tWidth)+(tWidth/2),y*tHeight+tHeight, colours[rand], lightness[rand]));

  rand = getRandomInt(0, colours.length);

  //upward point triangles
  tri.push(new Triangle(x*tWidth,y*tWidth,(x*tWidth)-(tWidth/2),y*tWidth+tHeight,(x*tWidth)+(tWidth/2),(y*tHeight)+tHeight, colours2[rand], lightness2[rand]));


 }
}


function Triangle(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3, colour, lightness) {
  this.x1 = x1;
  this.y1 = y1;
  this.x2 = x2;
  this.y2 = y2;
  this.x3 = x3;
  this.y3 = y3;
  this.colour = colour;
  this.lightness = lightness;
  var newlightness = lightness-20;
  //var area, areaOne, areaTwo, areaThree;
  var inside = true;

  this.calculateArea = function() {
    this.a = (x1 - x3);
    this.b = (y1 - y3);
    this.c = (x2 - x3);
    this.d = (y2 - y3);
    this.area = (0.5*Math.abs((this.a*this.d)-(this.b*this.c)));
    //console.log(this.area);
  };

  this.checkIfInside = function(mouseX, mouseY){
    this.areaOne = calculateArea(mouseX, mouseY, this.x2,this.y2,this.x3,this.y3);
    this.areaTwo = calculateArea(mouseX, mouseY, this.x1,this.y1,this.x3,this.y3);
    this.areaThree = calculateArea(mouseX, mouseY, this.x1,this.y1,this.x2,this.y2);
    if ((this.areaOne + this.areaTwo + this.areaThree)>this.area) {
      this.inside = true;
      //console.log(this.area);
    } else {
      this.inside = false;
    }
  };

  this.update = function(){
    if (this.inside) {
      //console.log(true);
      newlightness--;
      if (newlightness < this.lightness-20) {
        newlightness = this.lightness-20;
      }
    } else {
      newlightness = this.lightness+20;
    }
  };
  this.draw = function(){
    var c = "hsl(" + this.colour + ", " + newlightness + "%)";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(this.x1,this.y1);
    ctx.lineTo(this.x2,this.y2);
    ctx.lineTo(this.x3,this.y3);
    ctx.fillStyle = c;
    //ctx.strokeStyle = c;
    //ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  };
}
```

Note: this is not all of the code, just a portion where I think the problem lies.

Now, if you look at the pen then you'll see that this works - sort of. Some triangles light up a few of the ones beneath or next to them that are also the same colour (downward pointing triangles get their colour from a different array). I believe these also would come one after the other in the loop which makes them, so I'm guessing the problem is either with the loop or the way the triangles are drawn or constructed.

I've noticed that commenting out one of the tri.push() lines at a time to show only downward or upward triangles recreates the issue both times, and makes it slightly easier to see.

So, if anyone could take a peek and see if I've made some obvious mistake, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found the bug, but promise you won't bang your head on a wall ok ?

As you might know, a wrong parameter is just ignored by a Context2D, so if an 'undefined' or like sleeps through, so out of curiosity, in Triangle.draw i added :

```
var c = "hsl(" + this.colour + ", " + newlightness + "%)";
if (!this.colour) c='#FFF';
```

And some white triangles appeared.

So looking at the code that selects color, you used :

```
rand = getRandomInt(0, colours.length);
```

when the max index in an array is length - 1 !
So you have undefined colours, and your draw fails to use the right colour.
Just changing your rand pickingS (!you do it two times!) by :

```
rand = getRandomInt(0, colours.length-1);
```

fixes the issue... almost... sometimes it still fails...

But then i looked at the colour table... one is wrong (the second one : "145, 63%, 49%"), so it is ignored also when changing fillStyle. 
After correcting this one, all is fine !

Ouch !  :-)

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasn't aware that Context2D ignores errors (the reason I was confused is that no errors were logged, now I know). Thanks for taking the time to have a look, I really appreciate it - it's useful to see how you worked out the bugs too because I'm still learning, so yeah, it works now and I'm happy!

Comment: Also, yes - I do grab a new random int twice - is that bad? If I don't, the colours come in pairs and the whole thing appears to be less random. Maybe there's a smarter way? Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. For the rand thing, i just wanted to be sure you didn't forget the second call, that's all ! The fact that errors aren't notified by Javascript annoys me so much i now prefer Google Dart, no more hours lost for an error that Dart (among others) can detect even when you type !! Too bad there's no Dart codepen yet... Anyway good luck in your graphical adventures !